# What icon or symbol for endorse/ promote/ support?

Tags: gui-design, icons, iphone

Hi I'm working on an app that involves talents showing off their skills and what not, and users can endorse/ support them to get a chance to win a grand prize.

My problem is with using a **heart** icon, which generally represents **favorite** more than anything else. Also using a **thumbs up** generally represents that you **like** something.

Imagine backing someone on kickstarter, same idea. I thought of a fist or a fist bump...

Any thoughts suggestions as to what symbolism could be used for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the thumbs up symbol is so widely used now, it may be the most user friendly option to stick with. Another icon that might work for showing support would be one showing a coin going in a cup.

Comment: Coin going in a cup would be symbol of charity or support but not endorsement and approval.

Comment: A coin going in a cup would imply general support, but it also would imply endorsement. Kickstarter was referenced in the question as a similar model, where one endorses projects with money. Regardless, I think using the thumbs up icon would be more understandable to the average user.

Answer (score 0):

If the support is via donations, then perhaps a "money donation" icon e.g. [first search result](http://www.detroitareadiaperbank.org/Donate_198181145_std.jpg).

Edit: For support in a competition by voting, a [voting booth](http://www.thecoast.ca/binary/7720/vote.jpg) seems natural.

Comment: No it's not that kind of support. It's support or backing them in the sense that you like what they do, and want them to reach the finals and win the competition.

Comment: Then, from your description, the `thumbs up` is suitable. However, there may be a more suitable one - see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar decision on a project I am working on. I want users to **"appreciate"** posts by other users. I mulled over what icon worked (thumbs up was the #1 choice but it's now "loaded" by facebook.)

After much thought, I went with text. It's a fine choice if space or choice count is not an issue. Plus, there is no doubt what the meaning is.

Attached is my sample and note this very site uses text actions to good effect.
[image]